# Перемещение txt файлов с определенным текстом в другую папку C#

Tags: c#

У меня есть папка в которой находятся txt файлы с данными,как мне сортировать в отдельную папку по моим параметрам.
Приведу пример
У меня есть несколько txt файлов в которых разные данные и только в одном написано Hello World
И вот как мне только его отсортировать в отдельную папку.

Comment: Что у вас вызвало затруднение в этой задаче?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Моя проблема,в том что я не могу их сортировать :)

Comment: Можешь добавить все файлы в данном каталоге добавить в список. Затем перебором по всему списку найти конкретную фразу, и если есть совпадение, скопировать его в новый каталог.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения этой проблемы вам понадобятся класс [DirectoryInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=net-5.0) для получения содержимого директории, и класс [File](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=netframework-4.8) для чтения и копирования файлов

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: можете кодом показать?